# Phonegap 2.0 , Cordova external links

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a situation and I spend so much time in google with no success.

I want to open in my app (IOS), external links which are like that

`"<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">External Link</a>"` to open in safari not web view. where I have set up in "Cordova.plist"

`OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView : true`

Because I hav as well some Iframe inside my app, where I want to keep user in web view and not to leave the app.

An I have no idea why target="_blank" doesn't work, where here :

https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags it says:

"
**on iOS, if a domain is whitelisted, a link will take over the entire webview, unless the link's target is _blank, in which case it will open in the browser. If it is not, it will log an error on the device, while doing nothing from the user's perspective.**
"

I tried to use JS way as well,

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
```

with no success :(

PS: *I do have all my links in External host set up*

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you change `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to false, since it sounds like that is your goal...then only apply the target parameter to those you want to load in Safari

Comment: all opens in Safari, even the Iframe what I want to keep in the APP

Comment: Is Google Whitelisted? You could exclude Google from your whitelist, which should force it to open in the browser instead of the app while keeping your iFrames internal and whitelisted.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is this charmer in your MainViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSURL *url = [request URL];

// Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
// Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}
else {
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I was looking for hours to find your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It works with me using following setup:

Cordova.plist:

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: false

external Hosts: google.com
```

Link in Code:

```
< a target='_blank' href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=something'>
```

Hope it works for you as well :)